# system settings not showing all settings

Tags: pulseaudio, system-settings

This is a weird problem I am having after installing ubuntu 14.04. When I click on system settings, it shows only 7 fields:

Personal:

1. Language Support
2. Security & Privacy
3. Ubuntu One
4. Ubuntu Tweak

   Hardware:
5. Printers

   System:
6. Landscape Service
7. Software & Updates

Even when I click on sound settings or date and time settings the same thing happens.

I was having some problems with pulseaudio due to which I had tried changing its configuration files (Didn't make backups. Lesson Learnt). This led to even worse crashes. So I purged pulseaudio and reinstalled it in the hope that everything will be as it was. But now my sound is not working and there is no way to change any setting.

Comment: What's the output of `gnome-control-center --list`?

Answer (score 6):

I found an answer on here, I was having the same issue. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```